# UNIX domain SOCK_DGRAM Client - Connection refused

Tags: sockets, udp, datagram, unix-socket

Unix domain SOCK_DGRAM returns connection refused error. As we know, Datagram sockets are connection-less. I expect client, not to return any error on sendto() if server is not started yet. But how client returns connection refused error ?

Comment: Because it can't find the UNIX domain socket, because rthe server hasn't been started yet.

Comment: UDP is connection-less. Why client wants to depend on server to start? AF_INET UDP socket doesn’t throw error if server is not started.

Comment: Because it just sends the datagram to the router. There is no router in Unix-domain sockets, they are local, and the error can be detected immediately, and so it is. Do you really want *not* to know that the server hasn't started yet?